# Prestashop 1.6 product_list: get number of attached attribute combinations

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I'm building my first prestashop. I have a couple of products with attribute combinations that have an impact on the price. In list views, I would like to detect if a product has more than one combination attached to it, in order to display a 'from' before the price.

I have not been able to find a way to access anything related to attributes or combinations from the product_list.tpl. 
I found a function in product.php that might be suitable for what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public function hasAttributes()
{
    if (!Combination::isFeatureActive())
        return 0;
    return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue('
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa').'
        WHERE pa.`id_product` = '.(int)$this->id
    );
}
```

From product_list.tpl I can access other stuff inside the product class like e.g. 'features' and I was hoping to get the attributes in a similar way.
The only place I could find 'features' being declared as a variable was in the product controller, as part of this array:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array( ...
```

So I assumed that's the way to go, add a variable and point to the desired function inside the product class. but no matter what I enter here it just doesn't work out. What am I doing wrong? Is this the right approach at all?

Thanks in advance.

You can view the site at [rhum-martinique.de](http://rhum-martinique.de/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `ProductCore::getAttributeCombinaisons` and check its result with the `count` function

Add this function to the file `/config/config.inc.php`

```
function count_product_combinations($id_product)
{
    $product = new Product($id_product);
    return count($product->getAttributeCombinaisons(Context::getContext()->language->id));
}
```

Add this code to your tpl file:

```
{if count_product_combinations($product.id_product) > 1}
    <span class="price-prefix">{l s='From'}</span>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I already tried something like this with hasAttributes, but no dice. Unfortunately your solution didn't work either: Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeCombinaisons() on a non-object

Comment: posted: [product_list.tpl](http://pastebin.com/srUs7QnQ).  Your snippet is at line 105, currently commented out.

Comment: The variable `$product` is not an `Object` but an `Array`, I will edit my answer

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template...  {$productObj = new Product($product.id_product, false);}" unknown function "Product" <-- thrown in

Comment: It seems that smarty is confusing the class for a function

Comment: Edit: It's better to use an external function to instanciate the product object as smarty doesn't allow the previous syntax

Comment: Bingo! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your support.